# How to list only filenames removing directories and subdirectories

Tags: sed, awk, find, cut

How can I get the list of only filenames and remove directory and subdirectories using find, sed, awk, cut or any.

For e.g : I get list of all media files using find as such:

```
find /var/warehouse/* -type f \( -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.flv" -o -name "*.mp4" \) -exec ls {} +
```

Output:

```
/var/warehouse/movies/Blade/The.Bucket.List[2007]DvDrip-aXXo.avi
/var/warehouse/movies/Blade/The Lion King (1994).mkv
/var/warehouse/movies/Blade/The.Pursuit.of.Happyness.2006.DVD5.720p.BluRay.x264-REVEiLLE.en.mkv
/var/warehouse/movies/Blade/The Secret [Dual Audio] Upscaled 720p Ripped by FÅM€.mkv
/var/warehouse/movies/Blade/Yes.Man.2008.DvDRip-FxM.avi
/var/warehouse/movies/Bollywood/Bhaag Milkha Bhaag - DVDScr - XviD - 1CDRip - [DDR].avi
```

I wanted output as:

```
The.Bucket.List[2007]DvDrip-aXXo.avi
The Lion King (1994).mkv
The.Pursuit.of.Happyness.2006.DVD5.720p.BluRay.x264-REVEiLLE.en.mkv
The Secret [Dual Audio] Upscaled 720p Ripped by FÅM€.mkv
Yes.Man.2008.DvDRip-FxM.avi
Bhaag Milkha Bhaag - DVDScr - XviD - 1CDRip - [DDR].avi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
find /var/warehouse/* -type f \( -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mkv" \
    -o -name "*.flv" \
    -o -name "*.mp4" \) \
    -exec basename {} \;
```

or you can combine `find` with `sed`:

```
find /var/warehouse/* -type f \( -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mkv" \
    -o -name "*.flv" \
    -o -name "*.mp4" \) | sed -e 's!.*/!!'
```

Comment: Your perl example will fail on his files with whitespace/globs.

Comment: @arx: Remove that and replace with a `sed`.

Comment: @cuonglm : can u explain how sed syntax works here

Comment: @amolveer: `.*/` matches all thing until the last `/`, then we remove it. `!` is used as delimiter in sed subsitution command, `s!!!`.

Answer (score 3):

You have most of it already. You just need to change your `-exec` to a `-printf`

```
find /var/warehouse/* -type f \( -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.flv" -o -name "*.mp4" \) -printf "%f\n"
```

`%f` will print the name of the file that was found, ignoring the path to it.

You may also want to consider changing your `-name` to `-iname` (case insensitive match) so that it matches files like `*.Avi` and `*.AVI` as well.

Comment: `-printf` is not defined by POSIX, it only work at least in GNU find.

Comment: it does not work for the directories inside warehouse since those directories also get listed with the base filename
Output returned as :
Blade/The.Bucket.List[2007]DvDrip-aXXo.avi
Blade/The Lion King (1994).mkv
Blade/The.Pursuit.of.Happyness.2006.DVD5.720p.BluRay.x264-REVEiLLE.en.mkv
Blade/The Secret [Dual Audio] Upscaled 720p Ripped by FÅM€.mkv
Blade/Yes.Man.2008.DvDRip-FxM.avi
Bollywood/Bhaag Milkha Bhaag - DVDScr - XviD - 1CDRip - [DDR].avi
while I need list of only base filenames.

Comment: @amolveer You're right, that's my mistake. Should be %f instead of %P.